# How can I validate image sizes (expressed as e.g. “5X4”) using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have to do image size validation using JavaScript. The sizes are provided as text, in the form `nXn` — e.g. “5X4” or something.

I have done a test for whether the provided size contains an “X”:

```
if(inputVal.indexOf("X")==-1) 
{
$('#erSize').append("*Size should be (e.g) 6X4");
}
```

But this test accepts e.g. “aXg” also.

How can I check that the values entered either side of "X" are only integers?

Comment: can you show more code, please? This snipped is to vargue for helping you.

Comment: i dont think javascript has access to images sizes

Comment: The issue is entirely different if you are uploading a local picture or you are referencing an image already on the site...

Comment: @Ibu, @Alvaro... you guys understand it wrongly. I have to just enter text from text and need to do validation. i have mentioned as image size is only for easy understand.

Comment: @Ibu: question is tagged string, manipulation

Comment: @Sriram90: to be fair to @Ibu and @Alvaro, your question wasn’t particularly clear to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(/^\d+X\d+$/.test(inputVal)) // add i after the pattern to match x case-insensitive
{
    $('#erSize').append("*Size should be (e.g) 6X4");
}

// accepts "1X1"
// accepts "9999X9999"
// rejects "aaa1X1aaa"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Regular Expressions

```
var pattern = /[0-9]\X[0-9]/;
inp = "AXG"; //Sample
if(!pattern.test(inp))
 alert("Error");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hFTJb/

Comment: That’s a good start, but I don’t think it would match e.g. `10X12`. Also, do you need the \ before the `X`?

Comment: @Paul D.Waite Check out the fiddle, works fine. Yeah the \ before X is not required.

Comment: @K.A.G: Aha, of course, it does match `10X12`. It doesn’t return an error for `a10X12g`, but that might be fine for the OP’s purposes.

Comment: @ Paul D. Waite, Exactly. Hence the blunt and simple Reg exp. :)

Comment: @Paul D. Waite, Hey you're correct. it doesnt give error for as49X45.

Comment: @Sriram, its for strings of the form you requested - numberXnumber. Perhaps you require it in a format that supports both alphabets and numbers as well? I dont see its purpose though.

Comment: @K.A.G: If we’re being pedantic, your regex matches input strings that *contain* strings in the form @Sriram90 requested.

Comment: @Paul, you're right.This does solve @Sriram's conundrum right?

Comment: @K.A.G: I think, given that he’s trying to confirm that what’s entered looks like image dimensions, he wants to make sure that the entire string consists only of digits with one X in the middle. He’s accepted [an answer that does that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729590/how-can-i-validate-image-sizes-expressed-as-e-g-5x4-using-javascript/6729654#6729654) in any case.

Comment: @K.A.G . ya absolutely that's the string. i have asked in my question as the either side of x are only integers. any way thank u i didn't say that your ans is not correct. just notify your small problem. thats it..

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that by using the RegEx.

Use the regular expression as `/(\d+)X(\d+)/g`

```
function isValidInput() {
  var regex = new RegExp(/(\d+)X(\d+)/g);
  var match = regex.exec(inputVal);
  if (match == null) {
    $('#erSize').append("*Size should be (e.g) 6X4");
  } else {
    // here 'match' will be an array of 2 numeric values [D,D] where d is an integer.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

RegEx is probably the best way, I'll give "raw" example without regular expressions that is doing the same thing:

```
function ValidateImageSize(imgSize) {
    var arrDimensions = imgSize.toUpperCase().split("X");
    if (arrDimensions.length != 2)
        return false;
    var w = arrDimensions[0] * 1;
    var h = arrDimensions[1] * 1;
    return !isNaN(w) && !isNaN(h) && w > 0 && h > 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (!ValidateImageSize(inputVal)) {
    $('#erSize').append("*Size should be (e.g) 6X4");
}
```

Giving it as it's more readable than RegEx and you can control and understand each step.
[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/LTc3q/).